# Python request library giving wrong content when URL is correct

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am just a beginner to python web scraping and wanted to get the stock price from yahoo finance.
Here is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

stock="TSLA"
r = request.get(f"https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/{stock}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")

#Price
Price= soup1.find("span", class_="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").text

print("Price:"+ Price)
```

However the problem is the request.get gives 404  page not found.

```
print(r.text)

OUTPUT: <Response [404]>
```

Please help me in fixing this problem. Do i need to use headers and user agents. Or is it the cookies that are blocking me?

Comment: It's probably a user agent thing.  If I remove the "ca." from the domain it works fine.

Comment: You're scraping an entire webpage to get one stock price? Please read [ethical web scraping](https://towardsdatascience.com/ethics-in-web-scraping-b96b18136f01). And consider using a [stock market data API](https://rapidapi.com/blog/best-stock-api/).

Comment: No problem, data is generating using pandas. If you prefer to  this  way then I can give the solution .

Comment: @Fazlul I am fine with that i would love to see your solution please share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
stock="TSLA"
url = f"https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/{stock}"
r = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'})
data = pd.read_html(r.text)
print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Fazlul it works. Instead of using pandas i just used r.text. The header you used worked for me. @Fazlul

Answer (score 0):

A 404 error typically means that the url has not been found. You can read up more on it [here](https://blog.mozilla.org/en/products/firefox/whats-the-411-on-404/). So that means for some reason when your code makes a GET request to that url the server responds by saying hey, that url isn't here.

However, if I put your url into my browser it works fine for a valid stock name like APL. So the first thing I would check is are you putting the stock name in wrong in the code - if so it will probably give you a 404.

But calling it with a correct stock name also gave me a 404 error using your code. So the next thing I would in this situation is hit inspect on a page, click the network tab and then refresh so you can look at what your browser did to make the network call to the url of interest. If you replicate this, then you can access the page programmatically.

In my request headers, there was a cookie and some other things so a good way to get round this is using [requests sessions](https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/), which replicates this behaviour well. To do that, first install the library:

```
pip install requests-html
```

Then this code works for me:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession


session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/")
if response.status_code == 200:
    stock_quote_response = session.get(
        "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}".format("APL")
    )
    if stock_quote_response.status_code == 200:
        # Parse the response
    else:
        print("[*] Failed to get stock quote for stock {}".format("APL"))
        print(
            "{} {}".format(
                stock_quote_response.status_code, stock_quote_response.reason
            )
        )
```

Comment: Alex could you please give me an example of you code with it showing the stock price.